# How to use ObjectContext.LoadProperty with EnablePlanCaching disabled?

Tags: entity-framework-5, objectcontext

On an ObjectContext object, I'm using code like this to load navigation properties.

```
    context.LoadProperty(entity, navigationProperty, 
        System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

I would like to disable plan caching on queries that will be generated with this kind of call ?

Is it possible ?

Is there an alternative by wrapping the context with a DBContext ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a DBContext.

```
DbContext dbc = new DbContext(context, false);
dbc.Entry<T>(object).Reference<TReference>(@"ReferenceName").Query().DisablePlanCaching().Load();
dbc.Entry<T>(object).Collection<TCollection>(@"CollectionName").Query().DisablePlanCaching().Load();
```

with DisablePlanCaching extension method (inspired from the one found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2012/06/12/entity-framework-5-controlling-automatic-query-compilation.aspx)) as :

```
public static IQueryable<T> DisablePlanCaching<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    ObjectQuery<T> q = query as ObjectQuery<T>;
    if ( q == null )
        throw new InvalidOperationException(@"IQueryable<T> is not of type ObjectQuery<T>");

    q.EnablePlanCaching = false;
    return query;
}
```